How to achieve something like Partial Pre-rendering
I am trying to implement something like :
<header with login related components such as showing login/logout button depending on browser content /> 

<server side rendered or pre rendered list of names of companies /> 

A page where the desired output can be sampled : https://in.indeed.com/browsejobs/
Since we are using NextJS 14 and Partial Pre rendering is an experimental feature in Next 15, I want to understand what are the basic concepts to follow in achieving the above structure
